# My input boxes are not centering in React-Native

Tags: css, react-native

Let me just preface with that this is my first time using React Native so I have absolutely no idea what I'm doing. Please don't rip me apart if this is a dumb question...

Here is a picture of what I have right now...[image]

But what I'm going for is to have those input boxes and button in the middle of the screen.

All of this happened when I put that a container inside of the view. I am not completely sure how to use both column flex and row flex so I can have my input boxes aligned vertically and my button horizontally, so I was just playing around with it and this is what I got. My code will be below.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {Keyboard, Text, View, TextInput, TouchableWithoutFeedback, Alert, KeyboardAvoidingView, StyleSheet} from 'react-native';
import { Container, Content, Header, Body, Icon } from 'native-base';

import { Button, 
        Input } 
        from 'react-native-elements';

class Login extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <View style={styles.Form}>

                <Input
                keyboardType='email-address'
                placeholder='Email'
                style={{justifyContent: 'center',}}
                leftIcon={
                    <Icon
                    name='ios-person'
                    size={24}
                    color='black'
                    />
                }
                />

                <Input
                placeholder='Password'
                secureTextEntry='true'
                style={{justifyContent: 'center',}}
                leftIcon={
                    <Icon
                    name='ios-lock'
                    size={24}
                    color='black'
                    />
                }
                />
                <Container style={styles.ButtonContainer}>
                    <Button
                        style={styles.Button}
                        iconLeft
                        title='Login'
                    />

                    <Button
                        style={styles.Button}
                        iconLeft
                        title='Signup'
                    />
                </Container>
            </View>

        );
    }
}

export default Login;

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    Form: {
        flex: 1,
        flexDirection: 'column',
        justifyContent: 'center',
        alignItems: 'center',
        alignContent: 'center',
        paddingRight: 50,
        paddingLeft: 50,
    },

    ButtonContainer: {
        flex: 1,
        flexDirection: 'row',
        justifyContent: 'center',
    },

    Button: {
        flex: 1,
        paddingVertical: 10,
        textAlign:'center',
        padding: 5,
    }
})
```

Comment: just remove `flex:1` from both `ButtonContainer` and `Button`

Comment: Please read ask a good question : https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: @Ziyo That brought my buttons where I need them but my input boxes are still not centered.

Comment: Give your inputs a specific width and height, so they are the same. (e.g `width: '80%'` or `width: 120`)

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't being specific enough. When I said they weren't centering, I mean't vertically, not horizontally. What I'm trying to get in the end is two input boxes, and two buttons in the middle of the screen. The two buttons will be next to each other under the last input box, and the input boxes will be one on top of the other.

Comment: That should not be difficult. Give me 10 mins.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IMPORTANT! DO NOT COPY AND PASTE THIS CODE.
I have changed some Components in order to run this code on the browser. CHANGE THEM TO YOU OWN COMPONENTS!

I left red borders intentionally, so you could see where components are. This layout will give you a lot of flexibility. Play around with values, then remove those red lines.

```js
class Login extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.Form}>
        <View style={styles.Top}>
          <TextInput
            keyboardType="email-address"
            placeholder="Email"
            style={styles.Input}
          />
        </View>

        <View style={styles.Bottom}>
          <TextInput
            placeholder="Password"
            secureTextEntry="true"
            style={styles.Input}
          />
          <View style={styles.ButtonContainer}>
            <Button style={styles.Button} iconLeft title="Login" />

            <Button style={styles.Button} iconLeft title="Signup" />
          </View>
        </View>
      </View>
    );
  }
}

export default Login;

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  Bottom: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'flex-start',
    width: '100%',
    borderWidth: 1,
    borderColor: 'red',
  },
  Top: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'flex-end',
    width: '100%',
    borderWidth: 1,
    borderColor: 'red',
  },
  Input: {
    justifyContent: 'center',
    width: '80%',
    alignSelf: 'center',
    margin: 20,
    borderWidth: 1,
    borderColor: 'red',
  },
  Form: {
    flex: 1,
    flexDirection: 'column',
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
    alignContent: 'center',
    paddingRight: 50,
    paddingLeft: 50,
  },

  ButtonContainer: {
    flexDirection: 'row',
    justifyContent: 'center',
  },

  Button: {
    paddingVertical: 10,
    textAlign: 'center',
    padding: 5,
  },
});
```

Comment: Thank you so much!